# PHP/MYSQL second sql query doesn't work

Tags: php, mysql

So, I'm trying to run these two sql statements in the same file. The first sql query works just fine and I am able to loop through all of the entries just fine, but I need to sort out more of the entries through some more sql queries.

I need to use the `['tid']` of the entries to check if they have children in my database in the second sql query, after I get the second sql query working I will add a nother sql query to loop through the children and query a count of their use in another table. But I can't get the second sql code to even run.

At first I had them in their own function so I could access them when ever I needed but it wasn't working so I ended up here. When I try to use anything from the second sql query it just returns nothing, and if I add error reporting it doesn't report an error.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

```
$query = "
SELECT DISTINCT
    Homelectricaldb.taxonomy_term_data.tid,
    Homelectricaldb.taxonomy_term_data.vid,
    Homelectricaldb.taxonomy_term_data.name,
    Homelectricaldb.th.parent
FROM
    Homelectricaldb.taxonomy_term_data taxonomy_term_data
        LEFT JOIN
    Homelectricaldb.taxonomy_index taxonomy_index ON taxonomy_term_data.tid = taxonomy_index.tid
        LEFT JOIN
    Homelectricaldb.taxonomy_term_hierarchy th ON taxonomy_term_data.tid = th.tid
WHERE
    Homelectricaldb.taxonomy_index.tid IS NULL
        AND (Homelectricaldb.taxonomy_term_data.vid = 1
        OR Homelectricaldb.taxonomy_term_data.vid = 2
        OR Homelectricaldb.taxonomy_term_data.vid = 242)
";

$result = $con->query($query);
$output = Array();
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $children =  $con->query("SELECT td.tid FROM Homelectricaldb.taxonomy_term_data td LEFT JOIN taxonomy_term_hierarchy th ON th.tid = td.tid where th.parent = " . $row['tid']);
        if ($children > 0) {
            echo $row['name'] . " Has chidlren\n";
        } else {
            echo $row['name'] . "Has no children\n";
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:
I changed `if ($children > 0) {` to `if ($children->num_rows > 0) {` as @alex suggested and received a `Trying to get property of non-object`

Comment: you don't try to *to use anything from the second sql query* so probably just try to replace `if ($children > 0) {` with `if ($children->num_rows > 0) {` ?

Comment: Ooh thanks! That gave me an error. `Trying to get property of non-object.` It seems like it still isn't running the sql query. (not sarcastic, sorry if it seems that way)

Comment: How do you know it is not running the query?

Comment: I can't use anything from the query. if I did `print_r($children);` nothing happened.

Comment: why do you calling DB schema `Homelectricaldb` everyewhere ?

Comment: Because I'm using multiple databases one the same connection.

Comment: You should really try to avoid execute a query statement inside a loop.

Comment: I understand, and agree, I should avoid it, but I need to test all of the children connected to the tid. I'm not that great at SQL and speed wasn't a concern. This is part of a script that will run once a week or even once a month.

Comment: Yes, one thing that's wrong is having a second query. Another thing (and worse) is executing that query inside a loop.

Comment: @Strawberry, Is that the reason why it is not working?

Comment: No, that ain't the reason. What does the error message say? `PDO::errorInfo()` - ah wait, you're using the old mysql functions, right? `mysql_error()` then ...

Comment: You can't execute a statement when a cursor is still opened. You're somehow not retrieving the errors. On another note, you could just add the second sql to the first one, no need to split it in two.

Comment: You are displaying a classic anti-pattern of querying in a loop.  Think about writing the first query to gets all records at once. (i.e. JOIN first query with second)

Comment: No. You asked what you're doing wrong, so that's the question I answered.

Comment: @m02ph3u5 It doesn't return anything.

Comment: @Strawberry I rewrote the query to get the results I need from the start. Thank you for your suggestion. Should I delete this question or write an answer?

Comment: It's up to you; SO welcomes users answering their own questions